# Wordpress Query Posts from specific subcategory of Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Okay guys, this one has me somewhere between ripping my hair out and kicking in my monitor. It seems no matter what I try, no matter how many times I re-write the query, change terms, change syntax...I get nothing.
 So I have a website I am working on where we have a custom post type of 'Vinyl' for vinyl records of in an online collection the client wants displayed alphabetically, with a category of 'vinyls' inside the custom post type section. The client then further wanted to separate things down and create a child category within 'vinyls' called 'vinyl_ae' (Vinyls alphabetically sorted by the first letter A through E). Now, I have the issue where I am trying to query any post at all from the vinyl_ae category/sub-category/whatever the hell it is at this point, and NOTHING turns out. The only way I get any results at all is to set an else conditional for the if have_posts() statement. I'll try to include any all data I can here to help sort this mess out.

1. Custom post type - name : vinyl
2. main category -  name : VINYLs, slug : vinyls, ID : 3
3. child category - name : Vinyl A-E, slug : vinyl_ae, ID : 4571

[Screen Shots of all my category and sub-category layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuQex.jpg)

Here is my working Code Currently (take in mind I have stripped it down so much tonight there is not much left and I have tried so many different solutions to the point where I am practically copying and pasting based on results others are having)

```
<section id="main">
<div class="content-holder no-spacing">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-inner">
            <div id="ajax" class="records row">

            <?php
            $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post' ,
            'posts_per_page' => 6,
            'cat'         => '4571',
            'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
            'post_parent' => $parent); 
            $mv = new WP_Query($args);
            if ( $mv->have_posts() ) { 

            while ( $q->have_posts() ) {

            $serial = get_field('serial');
            $mv->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="serial-num"><?php echo $serial; ?></div>

            <?php } ?>

            <?php } else { ?>
            <em>Things Still Screwy</em>
            <?php } ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank any and all in advance for any help that can be given, I've thrown in the towel here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two things that you should consider in your sample code:

1. You should set `post_type` argument to your custom post type `vinyl` not the `post` post type.
2. If the `serial` is a field of your post you should call the `$mv->the_post();` line first and after that call the `$serial = get_field('serial');` statement, because before `the_post()` call, you can't access post's meta data.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was in such a haze I didn't catch any of that. You saved the day!